# error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `react-native-vector-icons/Feather`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-native

In React native I'm simply applying a **Flatlist** from react native library.
Succefully installed all libraries

**pakage.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "feather-icons-react": "^0.3.0",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.57.8",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.0.0-beta7",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Main from './components/MainComponents';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' + 'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android:
    'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (

        <Main />

    );
  }
}
```

**error log**

```
    error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `react-native-vector-icons/Feather` from `F:\React Native\FirstProject\node_modules\react-native-elements\src\helpers\getIconType.js`: Module `react-native-vector-icons/Feather` does not exist in the Haste module map
```

newbie to react native

Help will be highy appreciated

Thankyou

Comment: show the code of your Main component or wherever you are using Feather

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To install react-native-vector-icons, you need to install it, then link it. First run:
 `npm install react-native-vector-icons --save`
or if you use yarn
 `yarn add react-native-vector-icons`

Then, you will have to link it like this:
`react-native link react-native-vector-icons`

Answer (score 3):

1. close running packager
2. run react-native link react-native-vector-icons
3. run react-native start --reset-cache
4. Finally use react-native run-ios

Answer (score 2):

This command is worked in my case

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 1):

Watch for the import, cause it depends on the font family you registered.

In my case I used IonicIcons, so my Icon import is like this:

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
```

Then it can be used like:

```
<View>
  <Icon name="star-outline" size={50} color="navy" />
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you've installed the package with `yarn add react-native-vector-icons` and then reset packager cache with `react-native start --reset-cache`